# Can you make cesti adamantine?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, special-materials

I'm playing a Brawler and I'm wondering if it would be worth it to buy a pair of adamantine cesti to bypass DR and for sundering purposes.

Close weapon Mastery says the following:

> Close Weapon Mastery (Ex): At 5th level, a brawler’s damage with close weapons increases. When wielding a close weapon, she uses the unarmed strike damage of a brawler 4 levels lower instead of the base damage for that weapon (for example, a 5th-level Medium brawler wielding a punching dagger deals 1d6 points of damage instead of the weapon’s normal 1d4). If the weapon normally deals more damage than this, its damage is unchanged. This ability does not affect any other aspect of the weapon. The brawler can decide to use the weapon’s base damage instead of her adjusted unarmed strike damage—this must be declared before the attack roll is made.

Would getting these cesti work to just use my unarmed attacks to get the adamantine material abilities? Or would it not work?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [Gauntlets In Regards to Negating Damage Resistance on Unarmed Strikes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133569), [Brass knuckles on a Monk in Pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87302)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use cesti or brass knuckles made of special materials such as adamantine.

Per your CWM ability, you'll deal the unarmed damage of a brawler 4 levels lower with them.

There's a monk in my game with cold iron brass knuckles inscribed with the letters "E L F P U" and "N C H E R" on them. He's high enough level now that his unarmed strikes do cold iron damage anyway but he has sentimental attachment to them.

Of course when you're level 17 you won't need this any more either, but till then it'll be mighty handy when you meet a golem. (Get it? Handy?)

Also keep in mind there's some pretty inexpensive magic items and other enchants that'll do this for you too, like the [Forge Fist Amulet](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-forge-fist/).